# Fetch Currency on the basis of Country or time zone PHP, Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to get currency on the basis of country, suppose if i'm accessing my web page in US then my currency should be in Dollars and if i'm accessing my page in some other region lets suppose UAE so my currency should be in Durham.

i'm confused how to get such value, i've tried all posible way, such as geoip_time_zone_by_country_and_region();
geoip_region_by_name();
may be i'm not getting these in proper way. i'm doing it by using PHP and codeigniter.

Comment: Just An Advice. You can make a Common Function Which is Compare the Time Zone and return the Price According to it.

Comment: I've tried this but nothing is working properly, if you have any thing related to this or you can help out with example, will be appreciated :)

Comment: Did you get the TimeZone According to Country?

Comment: Yes I've the complete list of TimeZone including Country name, but still the matching is not working

Just for Example
<?php 
function get_time_zone($country,$region) {
  switch ($country) { 
case "US":
    switch ($region) { 
  case "AL":
}
}
get_time_zone($country, $Region);

Comment: Look At this Answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795673/how-can-i-automatically-convert-currency-on-the-basis-of-country

Comment: Another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282578/currency-conversion-using-php

Comment: Thank you very much ankit but this is a currency converter, this not the think which i need, its totally different from my question.

I want to get currency on the basis of region or country, not the currency converter.

Comment: This May Sure gone help you . http://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You acan use this url:
>
> ```
> http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip="ip address here"
> ```
>
> It will respond back the data in json format:
>
> ```
> {
> "as": "AS4755 TATA Communications formerly VSNL is Leading ISP",
> "city": "Bengaluru",
> "country": "India",
> "countryCode": "IN",
> "isp": "Tata Communications",
> "lat": 12.9833,
> "lon": 77.5833,
> "org": "Tata Communications",
> "query": "14.141.47.106",
> "region": "KA",
> "regionName": "Karnataka",
> "status": "success",
> "timezone": "Asia/Kolkata",
> "zip": ""
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

1. Currency Symbol
2. Country Flag
3. Currency Format
4. Other custom options

I am using all this in one of my project which is in production and I can share that with you.

**Step-1**

I am using a preferences table in which I keep the settings like this

[image: Preferences Table]

**Step-2**

In my controller I get country by IP and save the code in a variable

```
$geo_data = geolocation_by_ip($ip);
```

Reference : [Geo Location by IP](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Geo-Location-By-IP)

In my model I create a function to get preferences via country code

```
$data['preferences']=$this->My_Model->getPrefByCountryCode($geo_data['country_code']);
```

and save them in array and then I send it to the view

```
$this->load->view('path/to/my/view',$data);
```

In my view I just echo them

**Currency Format**

For currency formats I use [PHP money_format()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_money_format.asp) function and for second parameter in

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY,"en_US"); // I get money_format from database
```

The rest is done by the function and the view is rendered. I save Symbols and Flags as icons and images, get their urls and echo them. Ofcourse this might not be the perfect way but it can save a lot of research