# How to convert rupee as paise with php

Tags: php, currency

What is the correct way to display rupee as paise with php?

eg,

> 552.25 rupee = 55225 paise
>
> 100.00 rupee = 1000 paise

Comment: multiply by 100 !

Comment: Try with ... rupee * 100 = paise

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Currency Conversion using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282578/currency-conversion-using-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Rupees is equal to 100 Paise (paise is an indian & pakistan currency)

So, you should used this formula

```
$paise=your_currency*100;
```

if you have simple `552.25` rupees

```
$rs=552.25;
$paise=$rs*100;
```

if you have `552.25 rupee`. then

```
$rs=`552.25 rupee`;
preg_match('/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/', $rs, $matches);
$float_val= (float) $matches[1];
$paise=$float_val*100;
```

Answer (score -2):

Simple, You can do it by this way.

Like below :

```
$rs = 100*100. " paise";
```

Output :

```
10000 paise
```